# Fragment Class error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have fragment class in that i am calling the database handler method which takes model class as a argument which is Manager and that class takes two variable one is int and another one is String, but i am getting an error:

> The method addManager(Manager) in the type DatabaseConnection is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int, String)

Here is the code of the addManager() and where it's called

Fragment Class Manager

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

                     DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection(getActivity());
                     db.**addManager**(Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString()),    
                                         text2.getText().toString());
```

Database Handler

```
void addManager(Manager manager1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(M_ID, manager1.getMid());
    values.put(M_NAME, manager1.getMname()); // Name

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to make it work.

Option 1: Change addManager() to this

```
void addManager(int managerId, string managerName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(M_ID, managerId);
    values.put(M_NAME, managerName); // Name

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Option 2: Change the call parameter to this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection(getActivity());
   Manager aManager = new Manager();
   aManager.setMid(Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString()));
   aManager.setMname(text2.getText().toString());
   db.addManager(aManager);
}
```

Comment: Hi Isabel Thanks for your ans,

Comment: public int updatemanager(Manager manager) {
                 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                  values.put(M_ID, manager.getMid());
                  values.put(M_NAME, manager.getMname());
     
               // updating row
             int result= db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, M_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(manager.getMid()) });
            db.close();
         return result;
        } how to call this in a onther fragment

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: same like previous one i am calling the method updatemanager in my manager fragment but its not working fine so,that i commented my code which is in database handler and this method accepts model class as a argument as u can see, please suggest me what should i pass when i invoke this method

Comment: to invoke that method i am using this code----------

Comment: Manager mgr = new Manager();
    mgr.setMid(Integer.valueOf(text1.getText().toString()));
    mgr.setMname(text2.getText().toString());
db.updatemanager(mgr);

Comment: but i am getting null value

Comment: Your update query is malformed. Could you create a question so that I can post the answer. The comment is so difficult to read.

Comment: Dear, Isabel i asked the question please check it, if possible give  some suggetion. Thank You.